# Redundancy in American Usage

Tags: american-english

Why do Americans use so much redundancy? Is it because of their schooling or their every day influence? Or is it something totally different?

Examples:

- It was an even tie. (They reached the finish line together, making it a tie.)
- Other countries abroad.

Comment: I’m not certain that your assumption these are Americanisms is true. A search for “even tie” in COCA (Corpus of Contemporary American English) and BNC (British National Corpus) gave no examples of the usage you cite. A search for “countries abroad” gave 8 examples in COCA and 6 in BNC.

Comment: I didn't find the expression _even tie_ in the _New Oxford American Dictionary_ either. I do find _there was a tie for first place_ as example, though.

Comment: *there was a tie for first place* is normal, IMO.

Comment: I would like to see some evidence that this occurs significantly with Americans speaking English.  I don't recognize either of these phrases as common phrases.  Even if they were common, redundancy occurs throughout languages around the world, and I think it would be easy to find British English phrases that have some sort of redundancy.  Lastly, I don't see how anyone could answer this even if it were true and a special feature of American English.

Comment: I agree with Kosmonaut. All languages are rendundant; that is the reason why you can understand a sentence even if you cannot hear all the pronounced words.

Comment: My personal 2¢: I might use "other countries abroad" with "abroad" as a synonym of "overseas." That is, "other countries" include Canada and Mexico, but "other countries overseas" does not. Or in other words, I don't hear the phrase as redundant, just precise.

Comment: There's the infamous 'at this moment in time'.

Comment: I've definitely noticed this tendency towards redundancy in American English. The question seems fair to me.

Comment: For words that are pleonastic in themselves, look no further than "reiterate".

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Please do not make assumptions about *all* Americans. Perhaps what you're running into is regional variation. While living in the Northeast, we would say "10 a.m." or "10 o'clock in the morning". When I moved to the Midwest, I noticed I frequently hear people say "10 a.m. in the morning", which is ridiculously redundant because "a.m." already implies "before noon".

Comment: @ssakl: Uh? To which comment are you referring? Are you referring to _All languages are rendundant; that is the reason why you can understand a sentence even if you cannot hear all the pronounced words._?

Comment: @ssakl: I am not making assumptions about all Americans. In fact, I am not making assumptions about American English; if I would make assumptions about American English, then I would say _American is the most redundant language._

Comment: It is becoming a language in itself, almost. I suppose you have heard about it's sister language, whick they speak in Britain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give them the benefit of the doubt, maybe they do it for purposes of emphasis, for example this sentence:

> That is a tiny little fish you caught there!

The most common issue I see is with acronyms when the word is rarely broken out in common usage and people don't think about what the letters stand for.

> Can you tell me where the nearest ATM machine is?

Comment: Then I can put my PIN number in and get some cash.

Comment: The M in ATM already means machine; saying _ATM machine_ is redundant, but it's quite common.

Comment: OOOOOOHHHHHHHHH

Answer (score 4):

I think the (very few) examples you give are just general sloppiness, which can be encountered in all cultures, and not representative of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Most American dialects use constructions like that one there, and so, do many others in the rest of the English-speaking world, such as Cockney and Scots. Therefore, the outlier may be Standard English, which did not become the standard until around 300 years ago. Wikipedia has a good article on [double negatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative), a closely related form.

My own opinion is that the reason the redundancy survives is meter; which of the following sounds better?

1. "I can get no Satisfaction"
2. "I can't get no Satisfaction"
3. "I cannot get any Satisfaction"
4. "I can't get any Satisfaction"